# Nginx pattern matching in location

Tags: url, nginx, uri

I am trying to match all paths of particular pattern to some alias but it isn't working.

```
  location /*/ {
          alias /some/path;
  }
```

My requirement is that any url, e.g. `http://<domain>/{variable}`, should go to the alias and bring up the default page. The urls `http://example.com/xyz/hello.html` and `http://example.com/abc/hello.html` should resolve to the same location and refer to same page.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried **rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 last;** or something similar?

Comment: sorry I didnt get that. can you give me an example code snippet?

Comment: sorry, that was the code sample above, it rewrites http://example.com/xyz/hello.html to http://example.com/hello.html

Comment: Do I need to put this inside my location directive? can you specify how my location,server and alias look like? Sorry I couldnt figure out

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /$2 last;

location / {
  root /home;
}
```

Comment: This works but expects a directory under /home. for eg. if I access example.com/xyz/hello.html it expects a directory /home/xyz. I want it to take from /home for whatever path I give in the url. I really appreciate for all your help. Thanks

Comment: "should resolve to the same location and refer to same page." that workflow with rewrite does what you need, no? :)

Comment: No. actually example.com/xyz/hello.html is taking to /home/xyz location and example.com/abc/hello.html is taking to /home/abc location. I really appreciate for your help

Comment: @RickyM ok, can I ask you to update the question with more details (input, output) please?

Comment: I have static content in placed at /home which has a index.html. Now if I access example.com/xyz/hello.html or example.com/abc/hello.html it should server up the index.html present in /home. 

With the above code it tries so serve /home/<path>/index.html (i.e., /home/abc/index.html or /home/xyz/index.html) which is not present. Hope this makes sense

Comment: @RickyM what about using `alias` instead of `root` ?